# If and else with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class structure like in the following,

```
class class_A
{
    public bool isChecked;
    public int id;        
}

class class_B
{
    List<class_A> classAObjects=new List<class_A>();
}

class class_C
{
    List<class_B> classBObjects=new List<class_B>();
}
```

and have a list of objects created from class_C,

```
List<class_C> classCObjects=new List<class_C>();
```

I want to assign `true` or `false` to `class_A.isChecked` for each instance of `class_A` based on some condition. If the ID is 100, then it should assign `false`. Otherwise, it should assign `true`.

Here is my code right now:

```
classCObjects.ToList().ForEach(a=>a.classBObjects.ForEach(b=>b.classAObjects.ForEach(x=>x.isChecked=true)));
```

The above assign `true` to all. Does anyone know how to get what I need?

Comment: Add where clause. `ForEach(x=>x.isChecked=true).Where(x=>x.id!=100);`

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
classCObjects.ToList()
             .ForEach(a=>a.classBObjects
                 .ForEach(b=>b.classAObjects
                     .ForEach(x=>x.isChecked=x.id != 100)));
```

By the way, it's ugly to call ToList on a collection just so you can use `ForEach`. Instead, just iterate:

```
foreach (var a in classCObjects) {
    foreach (var b in a.classBObjects) {
        foreach (var x in b.classAObjects) {
            x.isChecked = x.id != 100;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's how I had done it earlier. I mean,  I had iterated using foreach loop. But I thought that is the one which is uglier. Don't you think LINQ is little bit cleaner and readable ? pls let me know what you think about it

Comment: `ForEach` is not part of LINQ at all. And consider readability is more important than elegance.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
classCObjects.ToList().ForEach(
   a=>a.classBObjects.ForEach(
     b=>b.classAObjects.ForEach(
       x=>x.isChecked= x.id != 100)));
```

Comment: Yes, he's looking for something like that, although I don't think this code will work.

Comment: yes...but it should assign "true" to "ischecked" if id is not 100. if id is 100, it should assign "false" to "ischecked"

Comment: Yes it will assign true for all except id = 100 and will assign false. +1 @Peyman